# How to set the monthly subscription for iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

iam doing the  one application.I want to set the monthly subscription for that application. Means I want to get the transaction receipt when I install the application on device. And every month user wants to renewal the subscription. If not renewal application not open.This is my requirement . So please tell me how can apply the subscription for total application .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the app to not open if third-party subscription ends.
That would look like a crash.

What you should make is when a user opens your app you tell him to renew the subscription and how.

Comment: That is ok.how can I get the transaction receipt when the app installs.and may I need to set any product identifier

Comment: I'm afraid, you can't get anything when the app installs. You can run code only when user launches your app.